# which Environment will be ideal for a card game?

Tags: windows, winforms, playing-cards

I'm currently programming a card game and I would like to make the game using Windows Forms but I'm running into problems with it.

The game is half real-time.  After the first move, the player will need to throw their card as fast as possible.  Which Environment should I make this game in?

I appologize if my question is unclear, English isn't my first language.  Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

WinForms is pretty much a dead end technology at this point but really any modern framework will be sufficient for you to tinker with building a card game.

Answer (score 0):

Java, VB.NET or C# (using [system.drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx))

You might also consider an off the shelf game making tool like [GameSalad](http://gamesalad.com/)